# Filing map in groovy without using list

Tags: list, groovy, hashmap, bonita

I'am trying to fill up my `HashMap` with objects witchout using `List<Order>`, I know that `.with` and it is used like foreach, but at first I have to put index `[0]`. How to proper fill those map?

```
Map<String, Object> orders = new HashMap<>()
        try {
            context.apiClient.getDAO(pl.bonita.integrator.OrderDAO.class).findByArchived(IsArchived, startIndex, maxRows)[0].with {
                Map<String, Object> order = new HashMap<>()
                if (!it) {
                    response = "No case with id ${processId}"
                }
                order.put("CaseId", it.getCaseId())
                order.put("AssignedName", it.assignedName)
                orders.put(it.getCaseId().toString(), order)
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = "Exception: " + e.getMessage()
        }
```

Comment: Your question lacks clarification. It sounds more like a refactoring request instead of asking specific question to a specific problem. We are missing the context, we don't know what "proper" means to you. Have you tried refactoring that code on your own? Did you face any problem we could be able to help you with?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak because of .[0].with I can get only first element of given response. My response have ten "Order" objects and I want to fill my mapy with some iteration.

Comment: So, have you tried iterating the list? Didn't it work?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak it works only for the first element of given response. and I need all of them

Comment: Your code does not iterate anything. Have you tried iterating collection returned by `findByArchived` method? Something as simple as for-each to fill the map with the data you need?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I know. I tryed and I can't. I am working with bonita studio, and I cant inport my generated Order object, so I need to handle without using returned List<Order>. The best way will be do it in the block like with, but I am new with groovy

Comment: Maybe you just need `each` method on array instead of `with`

Comment: @daggett This is what I needed. Thank You

Comment: If you want to build up a map, use `collectEntries`